# How to control Loading panel on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-3.5, devexpress

**Work on C#,Asp.net,** on my page Click on **AspxButton**  i want to show **loading panel** with text **processing....**, After complete the whole event work ,Loading panel become false.

On button click how to control **Loading Panel**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET AJAX, you can use the UpdateProgress control in conjunction with the UpdatePanel to show an element while the server is doing the processing.

Check out Scott Guthrie's blog for an [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/21/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-UpdateProgress-Control-and-AJAX-Activity-Image-Animations.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The following topic contains a code which shows how this can be done:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxLoadingPanelScriptsASPxClientLoadingPanel_Showtopic

Comment: Thanks for reply.My button have AutoPostback=true property.Click on the button i want to show the loading panel.Hope you get it.

Comment: @DevExpress Team I only got a ASPxGridView™ and Editors Suite license so I cannot use a ASPxLoadingPanel. Can't I just invoke the grid's builtin loading panel?

Answer (score 0):

If so, you may leave the AutoPostBack property set to true and handle the button's client-side Click event as shown in the topic I've mentioned above.  There is no need to hide the LoadingPanel in this case, it will be hidden automatically when a page is rendered in the client side.